# Variable is either giving me an Error msg or crashing when I run python

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

```
import random    
import asyncio    
import aiohttp
import discord

import json

from discord import Game

from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = ''

client = discord.Client()

botnum = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Online and Ready to Play!')
print(client.user.name)
print(client.user.id)
await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="With Emotions")) 
print('------')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
# we do not want the bot to reply to itself
if message.author == client.user:
    return
elif message.content.startswith('PeriBot'): ### Updated to elif which is more acceptable
    msg = "I'm Busy! D:<".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
elif botnum == 20: ### forgot a ":" and Updated to elif which is more acceptable
    msg = "You Clods are so loud!".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    botnum = 0 ### you were comparing and not setting botnum to 0
else:
    botnum += 1 ### This will add 1 to the preexisting number of botnum

client.run("Token")
```

Whenever I run this it gives me the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Discord Bots\peribot.py", line 33, in on_message
    elif botnum == 20: ### forgot a ":" and Updated to elif which is more acceptable
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'botnum' referenced before assignment
```

I have tried adding the `global` to the botnum which just causes a crash with python. I'm sure it is a simple fix but I am unable to find it.

Comment: What exactly happens when you add `global botnum` at the top of your `on_message` coroutine?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh As soon as I open it with python the python runner thing closes

Comment: With no error message?  Could you double check the indentation of your code in the question?

Comment: When I paste my code it doesnt automatically have the gray background, I have to add it myself with 4 spaces. If that changes anything?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh here it is exactly pasted except for removed Token https://pastebin.com/4132fLTT

Comment: `global botnum` goes inside the function

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I moved it inside the on_message and when I run it, it still automatically crashes without an error https://pastebin.com/6Ratzk2X

Comment: That code run fines for me, and produces the correct output.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh any idea why it is not working for me?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Apparently it was something with spacing and my text editor. I copied and pasted the code I pasted into Pastebin and it worked good just like I wanted it to! Thank you for your help :D